# Definition of Force Using Momentum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

When we use F = change in momentum / change in time, is that the average force applied? There could be different magnitudes of force applied over time to change the momentum (it could be instantaneous when the time approaches 0). So therefore, this equation must refer to the average force right? Also, when we say W = F * d, that is also average force because the same argument applies right? So if what I think is right, we usually don't write "average" but it's there by default.

Comment: Not quite, force is defined as $\vec{F}=\frac{d\vec{p}}{dt}$, if you are not familiar with calculus you might want to look at how a derivative is defined. Wikipedia isn't actually a bad place to start http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative

Comment: Over a finite time span, yes the time average force can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When we use F = change in momentum / change in time, is that the average force applied?

No. $F=\frac{dp}{dt}$ is the force in a negligibly small period of time. That is, the instantaneous force in this very moment.

$F$ is equal to the change of momentum $p$ in *this very moment*. There is no timespan, so there is nothing to take average of. $\frac{dp}{dt}$ is not an average change of $p$; it is the change of $p$ *right now*. Just like velocity $v$ is the instantaneous change of position *right now*, $v=\frac{dx}{dt}$, not an average.

> Also, when we say W = F * d, that is also average force because the same argument applies right?

No. The general expression is $W=\int F dx$, summing up the total force, changing or not, during the move over the distance $x$. If $F$ is constant, then you take it out of the integral:

$$W=\int F dx=F \int dx=Fx$$

So your formula holds for constant force.

Comment: Ok I got the first part and some of the second part. I know that the work done will be under the F and distance graph, and if we had a constant force then it would be a simple rectangle type so we can multiply force by the distance. But, if I do find the average force applied, can I use that with the distance to find the work done?

Comment: @user3765618 Yes, you have essentially stumbled onto a really crucial theorem in calculus called the mean value theorem which roughly states that "for any arbitrary curve, the area under the curve from 0 to x can be represented by a rectangle of width 0 to x of some particular height". So you can indeed get the same work done by just picking the correct average force (height of the rectangle).